# google map - wrong color

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I have this map:

http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk/Rabies/Sequences/Map/37037

the kmz can be accessed here:

http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk/Rabies/Sequences/GetKMZById?Id=37037

Unfortunately the polygons are blue rather than red (it looks ok if I open it in google earth - I avoided tags which are not supported in google map). Is there anything wrong with my kml/z? Is it ok that a 'wevservice' serves the kmz? Thanks.

Christian

Comment: This kml file opens in Google Earth with blue lines and polygons, not red. Could you change it to display red in Google Earth and republish it? So that your error could be reproduced by others.

Comment: I have updated the links (the kml is in a db). This is 'nice' and red in google earth but not in the browser (google map) - it is transparent blue. Please note that the link is created server side (a form post generates some kml which is stored in a db which gives one a id which is then used as link for the javascript (e.g. http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk/Rabies/Sequences/GetKMZById?Id=27027).

Answer (score 0):

I found [this list](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html) that displays what KML properties are supported in Google Maps, maybe that could help?

For instance, `colorMode`, `extrude` and `tessellate` is not supported. Don't know if that's the problem, but try to edit your KML to a simpler one without using the unsupported elements and see if that solves it.

Comment: thanks. i will have a look into this. the same kml structure works fine for this map: http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk/Rabies/Sequences/countries though

Comment: Just verified it. It does not help: http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk/Rabies/Sequences/Map/28028

Comment: That's strange. The working file uses KMZ instead of KML, have you tried to use KMZ in the non working case?

Comment: I have not got the compression working yet. however it shouldn't make any difference shouldn't it?

Comment: No, but if that's the only difference between the two files - it's worth a try just to find out. :-)

Comment: I have changed things - it spews out kmz (see new link). Still same problem - polygons are blue in google map and too transparent - but correct in google earth.